# Simple Injector Generic Registrations are not Resolved

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector IOC. I have below registration which not getting resolved, I am getting the error as shown below.

```
container.Register(
    typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), 
    typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).Assembly,
    Lifestyle.Singleton);

var changeFeedObserverFactory =
    (IChangeFeedObserverFactory)container.GetInstance(
        typeof(IChangeFeedObserverFactory));
```

> IQueryHandler<AggregatedSumPerDayQuery, AggregatedSumPerDayView> that is not registered. Please ensure IQueryHandler<AggregatedSumPerDayQuery, AggregatedSumPerDayView> is registered, or change the constructor of TeamViewService.

It's in a console app.

Please suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: Hi, Could you expose more code about the problem, like the implementation of IQueryHandler<AggregatedSumPerDayQuery, AggregatedSumPerDayView>.  Can you try use other generic parameter to see if the problem is in the IQueryHandler or on the generic parameters

Comment: Your question is confusing and needs more code. For instance, the example you show can't be thrown by Simple Injector when you call `GetInstance(
        typeof(IChangeFeedObserverFactory))`. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, since we can't see in which assemblies your types live, it's best to show an example that doesn't use the auto-registration syntax (i.e. don't show an example that calls `Register` while supplying an `Assembly`).